# Is it common to use: come first in the exams

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to use : " **I came first in my exams** " to mean: "**I achieved first rank in my class**", or does this sound dated?

https://www.wikihow.com/Come-First-in-Exams

I read it here, so I just thought if it sounds natural.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase sounds perfectly natural to me.

You could also say, "I scored the highest in my exams," which seems to have a slightly more literal and neutral connotation, instead of implying that the exam is a competition that can be "won".

Answer (score 0):

**Come first** means **to win first position in a competition**

> e.g I came first in the writing competition.

So it is idiomatic to say--

> I came first in my class.

Comment: Although in my American dialect *came in first* is more usual.  *Came first* is more literal: “Which came first, Paula Abdul's ‘Straight Up’ or the opening of the Beriln Wall?”

Comment: But "came in first" is used for sports competitions and not off tests.

Comment: *For not *off,that was a typo.